# How do I process Protocol Buffer files in Hadoop Map/Reduce using compression other than LZO?

Tags: hadoop, gzip, protocol-buffers, lzo, xz

I would like to use Hadoop Map/Reduce to process [delimited](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#writeDelimitedTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) Protocol Buffer files that are compressed using something other than LZO, e.g. `xz` or `gzip`. Twitter's elephant-bird library seems to mainly support reading protobuf files that are LZO compressed and thus doesn't seem to meet my needs. Is there an existing library or a standard approach to doing this?

(**NOTE:** As you can see by my choice of compression algorithms, it's not necessary for the solution to make the protobuf files splittable. Your answer doesn't even need to specify a particular compression algorithm, but should allow for at least one of the ones I mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the RAgzip patch for Hadoop for processing multiple map tasks for a large gzipped file: [RAgzip](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-491)